# Ubuntu 20.04 CUDA for torch unavailable by pytorch

Tags: pytorch

**Qustions:**

1. Should I reinstall **pytorch** after installed **nvida driver**
2. Is pytorch has **CUDA version** and **without CUDA version**?

****Desciptions:****

I installed N-videa and cUDA from ubuntu 20.4.
But still get cUDA not unavilable from pytorch, see python3 script

```
(torch) anaconda $ python3 -c  "import torch; print(f'CUDA:{torch.cuda.is_available()} CUDAs:{torch.cuda.device_count()}')"
CUDA:False CUDAs:0
```

**Checking n-vidia driver and CUDA**

> (torch) anaconda $ nvidia-smi
> Thu Jun 15 20:18:57 2023
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
> | NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
> |-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

```
(torch) anaconda $  /usr/local/cuda-12/bin/nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Apr__3_17:16:06_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.105
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32688072_0

(torch) anaconda $ lspci -k|grep VGA -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2484 (rev a1)
        DeviceName: VGA
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 87bc
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Could you add Pytorch version? Also, can you verify the versions are compatible? Helpful site; https://elenacliu-pytorch-cuda-driver.streamlit.app/

Answer (score 0):

After checked, My **pytorch** was CPU version only.
So I create new conda env and install pytorch again.

> $ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Then check again, it is working now!

```
$ python3 -c  "import torch; print(f'CUDA: {torch.zeros(1).cuda()} ; TorchVer: {torch.__version__}')"
CUDA: tensor([0.], device='cuda:0') ; TorchVer: 2.0.1

$ python3 -c  "import torch; print(f'CUDA: {torch.cuda.is_available()} CUDAs:{torch.cuda.device_count()}')"
CUDA:True CUDAs:1
```